# Why is the expected value of an exponential function $E[X] = \int\limits_{0}^{\infty}P(X>x)dx$?

Tags: probability-distributions, definite-integrals, exponential-function, expected-value

I couldn't find an answer to this, so I thought I would share the proof I came up with here. It turns out, this formula holds for all continuous random variables $X$ where $X \geq 0$.

Comment: This holds for all random variables $X\geq0$ that have a finite first moment

Comment: @OliverDiaz I know. I asked it this way because this is what I searched for initially and thought people may eventually have the same question.

Comment: @DavidParks: this question (the general one that is) has been addressed many times at MSE. A quick search for Fun ini's theorem plus distribution will show you some instances. That is why I marked it as duplicate. There is nothing wrong with duplicates. It is just better to let people do some search for questions before posting them. Otherwise dupes become too much to handle.

Answer (score 1):

The traditional formula for expected value is
$$E[X] = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)xdx.$$
where $f(x)$ is the density function for $X$. Assuming that $X \geq 0$, it follows that
$$E[X] = \int\limits_{0}^{\infty}f(x)xdx.$$
From here, we can use differentiation by parts to get
\begin{align*}
 E[X] & = \lim\limits_{t \to \infty}\int\limits_{0}^{t}f(x)xdx\\
& = \lim\limits_{t \to \infty}xF(x)\Big\rvert_{0}^{t} - \int\limits_{0}^{t}F(x)dx\\
& = \lim\limits_{t \to \infty}tF(t) - \int\limits_{0}^{t}F(x)dx & \text{since $F(0) = 0$}\\
& = \lim\limits_{t \to \infty}F(t)\int\limits_{0}^{t}1 - \int\limits_{0}^{t}F(x)dx & \text{since $\int\limits_{0}^{t}1 = t$}\\
& = \lim\limits_{t \to \infty}\int\limits_{0}^{t}F(t)(1-F(x))dx\\
& = \lim\limits_{t \to \infty}\int\limits_{0}^{t}F(t) \cdot P(X>x)dx\\
& = \int\limits_{0}^{\infty}P(X>x)dx & \text{since $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}F(t) = 1$}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Isn't the traditional formula $\mathsf EX=\int_{-\infty}^\infty x f(x)\,\mathrm dx$? Why the $f^\prime$? Do you mean to put $F^\prime$ with $F$ being the cdf?

Comment: @AaronHendrickson Yep, that was a typo that I accidentally copied to each line. Thanks for pointing it out!